# How to iterate type inside type in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Hi I am creating a procedure for insertion of meta data. I created types and I included 1 type in another type and in procedure I am iterating it to get the value. Since I am new to PostgreSQL I am not sure whether this works. also I am not able t test this. Can someone suggest how to do this.

```
Create Type Form_details as(
                     formName character varying(100),
                     submittedBy numeric,
                      createdDate date,    
                     updatedBy numeric,
                     updatedDate date,
                     comments character varying(500),
                  Sections Section[]  

)

create type Section as (
                           sectionName character varying(100),
                           sectionLabel character varying(100),                           
                           sectionOrder numeric                           



                     )
```

and the procedure I wrote is

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION form_insertion(formdetails form_details[])
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$

DECLARE 
         form_details_seq integer;
         section_seq integer;
         formName character varying(100);
         submittedBy numeric;
         createdDate date;    
         comments character varying(500);
                formStatusId numeric;

         sectionOrder numeric;
         sectionName character varying(100);
         sectionLabel character varying(100);
         attributeId numeric;

         I integer;
         J integer;
begin
FOR I IN 1..formdetails.COUNT

LOOP

formName             :=formdetails[I].formName;
formStatusId         :=formdetails[I].formStatusId;
comments             :=formdetails[I].comments;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', formName;

  FOR J IN 1..formdetails.Section.COUNT
   LOOP

   sectionName             :=formdetails[I].Section[J].sectionName;
 RAISE NOTICE '%', sectionName;

   END LOOP ;


END LOOP;

Return formName,sectionName;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

This is not complete procedure. but I am trying to test with this. Can you please let me know whether my approach is correct and how can I test it from DB side. How I will pass this parameter. By the way the Type I created is from Java object. this procedure will be calling from java end. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

the json is as follows

```
'{"functionId":"","subFunctionId":"","groupId":"Audit","formId":"","formName":"formname"submittedBy":"20001259","createdDate":"2015-08-06","updatedBy":"","updatedDate":"","comments":"","formStatusId":"","formStatus":"","formLanguage":"","isFormConfigured":"","formChange":"Yes","sectionLevelChange":"Yes","isActive":"","formVersionNo":"","formFooterDetails":"","formHeaderDetails":"","images":[{"imageId":"","imageTempId":"","imageTempUrl":"","imageName":"","imageUrl":"","isDeleted":"","imagesDesc":""}],"imagesDescLevel":"","sectionElements":[{"sectionElement":[{"sectionId":"","sectionTempId":"sectionId+DDMMHHSSSS","sectionName":"section1","sectionChange":"Yes","stepLevelChange":"Yes","sectionLabel":"","sectionOrder":"","outOfScopeSection":"false","punchListSection":"false","images":[{"imageId":"","imageTempId":"","imageTempUrl":"","imageName":"","imageUrl":"","isDeleted":"","imagesDesc":""}],"imagesDescLevel":"","isDeleted":"","stepElements":[{"stepElement":[{"stepId":"","stepTempId":"stepId+DDMMHHSSSS","stepName":"step1","stepLabel":"","stepOrder":"","stepChange":"Yes","questionLevelChange":"Yes","images":[{"imageId":"","imageTempId":"","imageTempUrl":"","imageName":"","imageUrl":"","isDeleted":"","imagesDesc":""}],"imagesDescLevel":"","isDeleted":"","questionAnswerElements":[{"questionAnswerElement":[{"questionId":"","questionClientUid":"","questionDescription":"","questionAccessibility":"","isPunchListQuestion":"","questionChange":"Yes","questionOrder":"","isDeleted":"","images":[{"imageId":"","imageTempId":"","imageTempUrl":"","imageName":"","imageUrl":"","isDeleted":"","imagesDesc":""}],"imagesDescLevel":"","answerId":"","answerClientUid":"","elements":[{"element":[{"elementId":"","elementMapId":"","clientUid":"","clientClass":"","imageTempId":"","imageTempUrl":"","elementType":"Question","elementOrder":"","elementArributuesProp":[{"attributeId":"","attributeName":"","defaultValue":""}],"elementArributuesVal":[{"value1":"item1"}],"rule":[{"ruleId":"1","ruleName":"Mandatory","formula":"i>a","formulaData":"i>50","isDeleted":"","addAction":[{"actionId":"1","actionDescription":"","actionTag":"","actionOutput":"","actionOutputValue":"","numberOfFields":"","isDeleted":""}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

I already posted same question, but I didn't receive any answers. hence I am doing this again.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,My question is given as answered, but I could not see any answers, May I know where i can see the answer given

Comment: Hi, Is it possible with a different approach such as below

I have a postgres functionand input parameter is json. I need to extract values from this JSON and insert it in different tables. 

Admin will be creating form,section,steps,question from front end and these data I will be getting as JSON and I need to insert the data into tables accordingly..

Please find the JSOn above in question